# How to read sqs message using lambda python in aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have tried to read message from sqs queue using boto client in lambda python.
But i face issue with `""errorMessage": "'sqs.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'receive_message'"," . couldnt find the root cause`. Anyone help on this

My code in lambda

```
import json
import boto3
client = boto3.resource('sqs','us-west-2')
queue_url='https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/050190852521/MyQueue'
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
        response = client.receive_message(
            QueueUrl=queue_url,
            AttributeNames=['SentTimestamp'],
            MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
            MessageAttributeNames=['All'],
            VisibilityTimeout=0,
            WaitTimeSeconds=0
        )
        print('entered')
        print('Received %s' % message)

        message = response['Messages'][0]
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Use `boto3.client` not `boto3.resource`? `client = boto3.client('sqs', 'us-west-2')`

Comment: Thank u..But i am facing issue after boto3.client ""errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ReceiveMessage operation: Access to the resource https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.",
  "errorType": "ClientError"," where to give permission. in sqs? in lamda i have all permissions

Answer (score 2):

the variable definition is not correct for sqs
the correct one should be

sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

Comment: Already i am writing lamda into aws..Why we need to set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY?

Comment: then no need for it, updated the answer

Comment: Thank u..But i am facing issue after boto3.client ""errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ReceiveMessage operation: Access to the resource us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com is denied.", "errorType": "ClientError"," where to give permission. in sqs? in lamda i have all permissions

Comment: that's a different issue, you need to create a different question as comments should be related to the main issue. thanks